# Evaluating line integral over an ellipse

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

How can I evaluate
$$\int\limits_C(1+x^2y)\ ds$$ where $C$ is the first quarter of the ellipse  $\frac{x^2}9+\frac{y^2}4=1$

I tried parameterizing the curve but I couldn't get rid of the square root $$\sqrt{9\sin^2t +4\cos^2t}$$
The last integral I have reached is $$\int_0^{\pi/2}(1+18\cos^2t\sin t)\sqrt{9\sin^2t +4\cos^2t} \ dt$$

Comment: Well, what tools do you have available? Can you parametrize the ellipse? Can you think of a way to use Green's theorem or a similar tool? What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Please keep in mind that this is not a do-my-homework service.

Comment: @T.Bongers see edit please

Comment: What is $ds$ ? ...

Comment: @JJacquelin $ds$ is the length element over the path . By parameterization it can be written as $ds=\sqrt{x^{'}(t)+y^{'}(t)}\ dt$

Comment: @user376343 this is not multiple integral to use the jacobian besides I parameterized the curve but I couldn't perform the integral. If you can perform the integral , It will be excellent.

Comment: @JohnHughes you catch me second time within few hours, good point!

Comment: @AsmM. Isn't it $ds=\sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2}dt$ ?  I Of course, I asked ro clarify this because there was something not consistent in the wording of the question. See my provisional answer for explanation about the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

There is a contradiction in the wording of the question.

Either 
$$\int\limits_C(1+x^2y)\ ds = \int_0^{\pi/2}(1+18\cos^2(t)\sin(t))\sqrt{9\sin^2(t) +4\cos^2(t)} \ dt$$
or 
$$\int\limits_C(1+x^2y^2)\ ds = \int_0^{\pi/2}(1+36\cos^2(t)\sin(t)^2)\sqrt{9\sin^2(t) +4\cos^2(t)} \ dt$$
Please clarify which one you intend to solve.

Or equivalently, by elimination of $x$ with $x^2=9-\frac94 y^2$ :
$$\int\limits_C(1+x^2y^2)\ ds = \frac18 \int_0^2(4+36y^2-9y^4)\sqrt{\frac{5y^2+16}{4-y^2}}dy$$
A closed form involves the Complete Elliptic Integral : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegral.html

Comment: Thanks. Edited now

Comment: OK. Now I agrees.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer, but merely a hint**

You might want to try substituting $u = \sin t$, so that $u^2 = \sin^2 t$, and $1-u^2 = \cos^2 t$. Of course, you have $du= \cos t dt$, but you can write this as $$du = \sqrt{1 - u^2} dt$$
i.e.
$$
dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} du
$$
and then you'll end up with an expression involving polynomials and square roots of a polynomial. But the polynomial will be a function of $u^2$ rather than $u$, which gives some small hope for further progress. I suspect an arctan will enter in somewhere. But who knows?